# R. Problem with a loop through character strings

Tags: r, loops

I create this function to summarize the results of a glm:

```
outcome_forest<-function(mod,var,sd){
  x<-summary(mod)
  y<-x$coefficients
  x_df<-as.data.frame(y)
  x_df$Estimate<-x_df[var,1]/sd
  x_df$ci_min<-x_df[var,1]-x_df[var,2]/sd
  x_df$ci_max<-x_df[var,1]+x_df[var,2]/sd
  return(x_df[var,c(1,5,6,4)])
}
```

Now I have different glm models:

```
mod_1<-glm(y_1~x_1+c_1+c_2,data=data_1, family = binomial)
mod_2<-glm(y_1~x_2+c_1+c_2,data=data_1, family = binomial)
```

I want to create a loop in order to pass my function to these two models:

```
thelist<-c("mod_1","mod_2")
sd<-c(0.58,0.98)
results<-list()
for(i in thelist){
  for(j in sd){
    results[[i]]<-outcome_forest(i,2,j)
  }
}
```

I obtained the followin error

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I’m guessing this is happening because of the quota marks in model_1 and model_2. But these quotes are needed in order to create a thelist vector which just those names and no the results of both regression models.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `outcome_forest` takes `mod` as an object, and you have it as a string `c("mod_1","mod_2")`. To make R evaluate that string as an object you need to use `eval(parse(text=...))`:

```
thelist<-c("mod_1","mod_2")
sd<-c(0.58,0.98)
results<-list()
for(i in thelist){
  for(j in sd){
    results[[i]]<-outcome_forest(eval(parse(text=i)),2,j)
  }
}
```

But this approach isn't too god, its better to place the "mod"'s in a list and looping trough that:

```
l = list(mod_1, mod_2)

thelist<-c("mod_1","mod_2")
sd<-c(0.58,0.98)
results<-list()
for(i in 1:2){
  for(j in sd){
    results[[thelist[i]]]<-outcome_forest(l[[i]],2,j)
  }
}
```

Or avoid creating `thelist` by naming `results` later:

```
sd<-c(0.58,0.98)
results<-list()
for(i in 1:2){
    for(j in sd){
        results[[i]]<-outcome_forest(l[[i]],2,j)
    }
}

names(results) = c("mod_1","mod_2")
```

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo!

Comment: @Francisco I made an edit of better approaches! And if it solved your question, accept the answer so it marks this post as solved :)

Comment: If you just want to get an object from it's name, `get(i)` would be safer than `eval(parse(text=i))`